# Spark jdbc batch processing not inserting all records

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

In my spark job, I'm using jdbc batch processing to insert records into MySQL. But I noticed that all the records were not making it into MySQL. For example;

```
//count records before insert
println(s"dataframe: ${dataframe.count()}")

dataframe.foreachPartition(partition => {

  Class.forName(jdbcDriver)
  val dbConnection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password)

  var preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = null
  dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false)
  val batchSize = 100

  partition.grouped(batchSize).foreach(batch => {
    batch.foreach(row => {
      val productName = row.getString(row.fieldIndex("productName"))
      val quantity = row.getLong(row.fieldIndex("quantity"))
      val sqlString =
        s"""
           |INSERT INTO myDb.product (productName, quantity)
           |VALUES (?, ?)
          """.stripMargin

      preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString)
      preparedStatement.setString(1, productName)
      preparedStatement.setLong(2, quantity)

      preparedStatement.addBatch()
    })

    preparedStatement.executeBatch()
    dbConnection.commit()
    preparedStatement.close()
  })
  dbConnection.close()
})
```

I see 650 records in the `dataframe.count` but when I checked mysql, I see 195 records. And this is deterministic. I tried different batch sizes and still see the same number. But when I moved `preparedStatement.executeBatch()` inside the `batch.foreach()` i.e. the next line right after `preparedStatement.addBatch()`, I see the full 650 records in mysql..which isnt batching the insert statements anymore as its executing it immediately after adding it within a single iteration. What could be the issue preventing batching the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're creating a new `preparedStatement` in each iteration, which means `preparedStatement.executeBatch()` is applied to the last batch only i.e. 195 instead of 650 records. Instead, you should create one preparedStatement then substitute the parameters in the iteration, like this:

```
dataframe.foreachPartition(partition => {

  Class.forName(jdbcDriver)
  val dbConnection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password)

  val sqlString =
        s"""
           |INSERT INTO myDb.product (productName, quantity)
           |VALUES (?, ?)
          """.stripMargin

  var preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString)

  dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false)
  val batchSize = 100

  partition.grouped(batchSize).foreach(batch => {
    batch.foreach(row => {
      val productName = row.getString(row.fieldIndex("productName"))
      val quantity = row.getLong(row.fieldIndex("quantity"))
      

      preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString)
      preparedStatement.setString(1, productName)
      preparedStatement.setLong(2, quantity)

      preparedStatement.addBatch()
    })

    preparedStatement.executeBatch()
    dbConnection.commit()
    preparedStatement.close()
  })
  dbConnection.close()
})
```